# Adding to arraylist breaking application

Tags: java, constructor

When I try to run my program I am unable to add to my array list. I have initialized the variables used in my constructors and passed on these variables where necessary and seem to have done this in the exact same manner as my peers but for me this isn't working.

Does anyone see any issues with my arraylist which could be causing this error?

```
public void AddResource(String name, String Racf) {
        Resource r = new Resource(name, Racf);
        resource.add(r);
    }
```

Actual array list declaration

```
ArrayList<Resource> resource;
```

GUI implementation

```
public void handleSubmit() {

        String name = textName.getText();
        String Racf = textracf.getText();        
        qa.AddResource(name, Racf);
```

edit - When I navigate to the add resource page on my GUI and fill in the two boxes textName and textracf and click submit my application breaks. Above I have what is happening when I click submit, eclipse appears to be pointing towards "resource.add(r);" as causing the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkO1Z.jpg

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We cannot tell what is happening from what you've posted as most of the relevant context is missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: + please provide also the exact error with the stacktrace that you're facing

Comment: Where is the initialisation of the list?

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images, as this is not useful to others searching for this question in the future.  Please instead edit the question and include the error message in the question itself.

Comment: *I have initialized the variables used in my constructors*. Really??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you initialized your arraylist?(calling constructor to create a new arraylist.

`ArrayList <Resource>  resource = new ArrayList <Resource> ();`

Also I hope you have imported java.util.ArrayList